# Monitor Amazon SQS with CloudWatch over two metrics

Tags: notifications, monitoring, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am sending messages to the queue via cron. So my queue receives thousands of messages at a time and then it processes those messages. 
Now I want to set a monitor such that it notifies me when there are messages available but not a single message is processed in an hour.

It can be possible by using two metrics, 1)NumberOfMessagesSent and 2)ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible. (NumberOfMessagesSent <= 0  AND ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible > 0)

But in CloudWatch, I cannot set a combination of two metrics to set an alarm. Can anyone suggest how can I implement this? Or is there any other alternate monitoring system or way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you use the ApproximateAgeOfOldestMessage metric instead? It represents the age of the oldest non deleted message in the queue in terms of the number of seconds. Couldn't you alarm when this exceeds e.g. 1hr?

Comment: @mickzer Thanks for your answer. I have thought that as well. But in my case, the oldest message approx age is 72 hours sometimes, as I am scheduling more than thousands of messages a time in a week. Some of the tasks take too much time to complete as there is a waiting period involved in the task. So if my celery stops working then, I will get to know maybe after 3 days. So that I am looking for some alternate solution which can alert me in few minutes or hours.